# Not able to add JBOSS EAP in the runtime environments in spring tool suite

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, spring-tool-suite

I am not able to see JBOSS EAP v. 7.0.0 so that I can add in the runtime environments in Spring tool suite. I have set the environment variables Java Home, JRE HOme, Maven Home and JBOSS home. I have set the path variables also for Java. Is there any additional configuration to be done. I have also copied the jboss-modules.jar to the JDK location. I have restarted STS and machine also. [image]. I have tried searching but could not find why this is happening. I have Java latest version 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `JBoss Tools` from the Eclipse Marketplace into your Spring Tool Suite installation to get the specific server adapters for all the JBoss server environments.

Comment: Thank you Martin. After some time my spring tool suite throws JBOSS EAP 7.3 failed to start and then restart STS and it works :(. Can you help?

Comment: That is probably a question for the team working on the JBoss EAP 7.3 itself. Sorry.